# Error: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel 8 me lanza el error array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given al llevar a cabo la actualización de un registro en base de datos. Sin embargo, si actualiza el registro y no veo donde está el problema. Os dejo el código para ver si me podéis indicar cuál es el problema.

Controlador:

```
try {
        $showclient = Client::findOrfail($id);
        
        $showclient->update(
            [
                'cif'  =>  $request->cif,
                'company'   =>  $request->company,
                'corporateaddress'  =>  $request->corporateaddress,
                'postalcode'    =>  $request->postalcode,
                'locality'  =>  $request->locality,
                'province'  =>  $request->province,
                'telephone' =>  $request->telephone,
                'mobile'    =>  $request->mobile,
                'type'  =>  $request->type,
                'contactname'   =>  $request->contactname,
                'telephonecontact'  =>  $request->telephonecontact,
                'mobilecontact' =>  $request->mobilecontact,
                'emailcontact'  =>  $request->emailcontact,
            ]
        );

        Log::info(
            '¡¡CLIENTE ACTUALIZADO!!. 
            Actualizados los datos del cliente con ID: '
            . $request->id
        );

        return view('admin.clients.show', $showclient->id)->with(
            'success', 
            'Los datos del cliente indicado han sido actualizados correctamente.'
        );
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Log::error(
            '¡¡ERROR EN ACTUALIZACIÓN DE CLIENTE!!, Operación Cancelada. 
            Mensaje de error:' . $th->getMessage()
        );
        
        return redirect()->route('admin.clients.index')->with(
            'error', 'Error en el proceso de actualización. 
            Contacte con el administrador del sistema. Error: '
            . $th->getMessage()
        );
    }
```

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos lo que obtienes en tu último log cuando ocurre el error? Puedes crear un pastebin.

Comment: Hola Jonatan, el log me muestra el siguiente error: 

[2021-05-17 17:17:09] local.ERROR: ¡¡ERROR EN ACTUALIZACIÓN DE CLIENTE!!, Operación Cancelada. Mensaje de error: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given. 

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el return de la vista

```
return view('admin.clients.show', $showclient->id)->with(
    'success', 
    'Los datos del cliente indicado han sido actualizados correctamente.'
);
```

El segundo parametro del helper `view` debe de ser un array y estas enviando un int ($showclient->id)

prueba asi (['id' => $showclient->id]) :

```
return view('admin.clients.show', ['id' => $showclient->id])->with(
    'success', 
    'Los datos del cliente indicado han sido actualizados correctamente.'
);
```

Comment: Gracias compañero. Un saludo.